# is it possible to generate EPC Qr-Code using zxing?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, qr-code, barcode, zxing

currently i'm using zxing to generate qr-code, but scanner from banking app can't recognize it.

is it possible to generate EPC Qr-Code using zxing? or is there any another way generate the qr from another library?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, should be. zxing generates QR-Codes. The EPC is an usual QR-Code with just a standardization of the content. I'd say you need to check the content of your QR-Code and look if it fits into. See https://www.europeanpaymentscouncil.eu/document-library/guidance-documents/quick-response-code-guidelines-enable-data-capture-initiation

Comment: ColdFusion? (I saw that the tag was removed.)  We settled on using Zint (command line) to generate SVG & PNG bar codes. https://zint.org.uk/

Comment: @AndreasRu

is there any way to test the qr code is working or not? i tried qr with common scanner it works, but when my friend try with banking app in his country it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe the banking app that your friend is using requires different specifications. What I'd do is, tell him to give you a working QR code (that works in his banking app), then read it with a QR scanner and have a look at the data. Try to recreate that exact content with zxing, compare your created QR code with his working QR code.

Comment: Or try an API that creates EU compliant payment QR codes: https://apistax.io/docs/epc-qr-code